# Strict Standards: Declaration should be compatible with PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, zend-framework2

I am trying to just run the code that is developed by other team . I configured and run project but i am getting following error that is new for me.

> Strict Standards: Declaration of DB_Statement_1::execute() should be
>   compatible with PDOStatement::execute($bound_input_params = NULL) in
>   /virtualhosts/libolution/DB/Statement.1.php on line 12
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of DB_Statement_1::fetch() should be compatible with PDOStatement::fetch($how = NULL, $orientation = NULL,
>   $offset = NULL) in /virtualhosts/libolution/DB/Statement.1.php on line
>   12

Line # 12 is following here .

```
/**
 * A statement class that implements DB_IStatement_1
 * NOTE: in most cases, you should be type-hinting for DB_IStatement_1
 * @author Andrew Minerd <andrew.minerd@sellingsource.com>
 */ 
   following line is #12
  class DB_Statement_1 extends PDOStatement implements DB_IStatement_1
{   public function execute(array $args = NULL)
    {
        // apparently, PDO counts the number of arguments to indicate missing
        // optional parameters, rather than relying on a default value
        $result = ($args !== NULL)
            ? parent::execute($args)
            : parent::execute();

        if ($result === FALSE)
        {
            throw new PDOException('Could not execute statement');
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Fetches a single row
     *
     * @param int $fetch_mode
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fetch($fetch_mode = DB_IStatement_1::FETCH_ASSOC)
    {
        return parent::fetch($fetch_mode);
    }
```

There are following classes in same package .

```
DatabaseConfigPool.1.php  MSSQLAdapter.1.php           MySQL4Adapter.1.php           ODBCConfig.1.php              TransactionAbortedException.1.php
EmulatedPrepare.1.php     MSSQLAdapterException.1.php  MySQL4AdapterException.1.php  PoolConfig.1.php              TransactionManager.1.php
FailoverConfig.1.php      MSSQLConfig.1.php            MySQL4StatementAdapter.1.php  Profiler                      Util
IConnection.1.php         MSSQLConfig.2.php            MySQLConfig.1.php             Query.1.php                   Util.1.php
IDatabaseConfig.1.php     MSSQLStatementAdapter.1.php  MySQLiAdapter.1.php           SQLiteConfig.1.php
IStatement.1.php          MultiplexConfig.1.php        MySQLiAdapterException.1.php  Statement.1.php
[vendorapi@808680-app2 DB]$ nano Statement.1.php
```

so which one of them is being overridden .

thanks to all

Comment: a DB wrapper is being built on top of PDO? 0_o

Comment: I.e. your method signatures have to match those that you're overriding.

Comment: but there is no DB_IStatement_1 interface or class in DB package

Comment: Looks like a pretty bad package then.

Comment: i have mentioned all classes that are in same package.

Comment: @JonStirling yes . that team was using old frameworks and a lot of useless things.

Comment: You have 3 options. 1) Stop using the package (recommended), 2) Fix the issues with the package or 3) Remove strict standards errors from reporting (they're not actually "errors").

Comment: @JonStirling i am unable to connect to database because of this issue

Comment: have you noticed a note that is commented before the class initialization Note:  in most cases, you should be type-hinting for DB_IStatement_1 .  and same name class implementing same interface.why?

Comment: @WaqasRana I do not believe that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to an upgrade in PHP versions, and how PHP handles different errors in PHP 5.4+

Firstly, you could disable strict errors to get rid of this error like so:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

Notice the E_STRICT - this is new to PHP 5.4+

However, if you want to keep the strict errors you could get rid of them by changing the code. You will need to ensure the classes overriding have the correct prototype/definition to get rid of the error.

case 1)

```
class DB_Statement_1 extends PDOStatement implements DB_IStatement_1
{   
    public function execute($args = NULL) { ... }

    ....
}
```

Remove the 'array' Type hint as the parent class doesn't have one, that should rid you off the first error etc.

Comment: thanks  i changed the code as you said and Ist warning is gone but actual issue is i am getting that "unable to connect to database"  . that is a  critical problem  .

Comment: but that's totally different to what you've said in the question - those two errors have nothing to do with connecting to the db..